# Appcelerator Android CloudPush - callback is called but notification isn't cleared

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I tested with SDK 5.1.1 on my Android 5.0.2 - HTC One M7.

The issue:

With ti.cloudpush, if I receive a notification but leave it there without clicking it. Instead I launch my app from launcher. Then the callback function is called but the notification isn't cleared. If later I click the notification, it will launch the app but no callback is called.

Can anyone confirm this behavior? I filed a jira ticket [here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-279), but Appc Team kept saying they couldn't re-produce.

Sample code and my configuration are in the jira ticket above. Please test and let me know if it's just me or a bug. Thanks!

Comment: It's always very frustrating when an issues does not reproduce. It does seem like AppC support has followed the same steps you did. Do you have another Android device you could test on to verify if it is indeed related to the specific device?

Comment: Good suggestion. I just tested it on Nexus 7, Android 6.0. I can re-produce it....

Comment: Well, that seems to underline that it's an issue with either your code (which looks fine) or Titanium/Android. I'd suggest you add this to the ticket and ask them to retry. Let's continue on that JIRA ticket as well since Stack Overflow is not meant to be used for bug reports.

Comment: Yeah, I left a comment there a while ago. I just did it again. But the ticket is marked as resolved. My past experience told me that I have to create another ticket. Otherwise this one will never be opened again....

Comment: I see the ticket has been reopened.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you might be able to clear the notifications by calling http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.NotificationManager-method-cancelAll from the callback.

Comment: Unfortunately, my app may also have some other local notifications that shouldn't be canceled when push notification callback is called.

Comment: Yes, that won't work then. Did you see my comment on your initial question? Do you have another Android device to test with to see if it might just be that HTC?